# Looping through children in a foreach loop

Tags: unity, gameobject, hierarchy

I have a gameobject with a bunch of empty gameobjects as children that I want to use as spawn positions.

I want to loop through each of these positions and have a certain amount of probability that an object spawns.

How could I write a foreach loop that takes the parent object and loops through all its children like it would with an array?

Comment: What engine or tech stack are you using?

Comment: I'm using unity

Comment: So presumably you read [the documentation on the Unity Transform component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) to learn how to iterate its children? Where did you run into trouble applying this to your case?

Comment: Well your presumption was wrong, I couldn't find the documentation lol thank you very much.

Comment: Next time, remember to search first - the very first Google result for "unity iterate child objects" includes this technique. Don't underestimate your ability to find your own answers! :)

Answer (score 4):

By itself, the transform class implements the **[IEnumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) (with Transform as the generic type)** interface, which allows you to use a **foreach** with a transform as the interable object. You could also use a normal for loop, using **[Transform.GetChild(int)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)**. Examples:

```
foreach(Transform child in transform)
{
    /// All your stuff with child here...
}

for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    /// All your stuff with transform.GetChild(i) here...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good coding practice would result in the following code:

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject gb;    //outside the function

foreach (Transform child in gb.transform)
{
    Debug.Log("Name Of Child " + child.transform.name);
}
```

Comment: What is it about this that you would consider to be an improvement over the existing answer, which also shows how to write this foreach loop?